# If $x,y$ are ordinals and $x \cong y$ then $x = y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> If $x,y$ are ordinals and $x \cong y$ then $x = y$

The proof goes as follows;

Suppose $f$ is an isomorphism between $x$ and $y$ then show $f$ is the identity map.

Assume that $f$ is not the identity map. Consider the least element $z$ of $x$. s.t. $f(z) \neq z$. But then $f(w) = w,\forall w \in z$.

Now the set of predecessors of $f(z)$ is $f(w)$ for $w \in z$, which is $z$ itself. So $f(z) = z$. Contradiction.

I don't really understand the proof, how can you say $w \in z$ when $z$ is already the least element and then assume $f(w) = w$ when we've basically stated in our contradiction that it cannot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $z$ is the least element that satisfies the condition $f(z) \ne z$.  $w \in z$ is possible, but only if $f(w) = w$.

Comment: ok I think I get it, I read it so $z$ was least element of $x$ (so $z = \emptyset$) which is why it didn't make sense to me. Thanks.